# Retrieving data from xml API with AJAX

Tags: ajax, xml

I'm trying to retrieve data from an api, could someone help me on how to grab the node value of some child tags in an element in ajax? My XML api looks like this:

```
<distance ...>
<status>...</status>
<car>
<name>Golf</name>
<year>2016</year>
</car>
......
<car>
<name>BMW</name>
<year>2017</year>
</car>
</distance>
```

How can I retrieve all names and years tag values? Below is the script, I wrote comments in the area where I need help. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <script>
                function searchXML()
                {
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var url = "https://www.example.se/api/products/xml";
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                            console.log(xmlhttp.responseXML);
                            //Here I need help on how to retrieve data.
                            //when I used document.get....., I was getting .getElementsByClassName instead of getElementsById

                        }
                    };
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            </script>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>The returned data under this text</h2>
            <div id="mydata">
            </div>
            <button type="button" onclick="searchXML()">Get data</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: how about converting xml to json...the usabuility becomes easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the XML DOm Manipulation API'S  `var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;`

the *nodeValue* returns the node value

here is an example XML..

```
<bookstore>

<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web" cover="paperback">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

that is being parsed for node value as

**(Sorry for the CORS error...the code snippet will work on firefox)**

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
    var y = x.childNodes[0];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    y.nodeValue;    // gets the node value
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```